# auto update the html dom for all the users whenever there's change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am sorry for asking such a noob question. But I saw a video very long time ago and I think it was a framework based on jquery, where if a user makes some CRUD changes to an object, the object's properties are auto updated not only for 1 user, but on all the other users browser. I am trying to find it but I am all lost! I would really really appreciate if you could help me out. Thank you!

Comment: what backend you use?

Comment: Its a python framework - django

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets say you have a html form that looks like this

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="firstName" value="Jackson" />
    <input type="text" name="lastName" value="Rivera" />
    <textarea name="lifestory">
        When i was 2yo, spot died...
    </textarea> 
</form>
```

simply add an `OnChange` event on every element you want to dynamicly change:

```
<form>
    <input .. ..  onchange="shareValueWithOthers(this.name, this.value)"/>
    <input .. .. onchange="shareValueWithOthers(this.name, this.value)"/>
    <textarea onchange="shareValueWithOthers(this.name, this.innerHTML)">
        When i was 2yo, spot died...
    </textarea> 
</form>
```

Notice that a change of the elements value (or in the case of the textarea - it's contents) causes the function `shareValueWithOthers(this.name, this.value)` starts to run. `this.name` is the variable for the name, `this.value` is the variable for the value, `this.innerHTML` is the variable for the contents.

---

Now you have to write a Javascript function so you can send the changes to the server. Look into [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/Ajax/). Make a function that sends a POST request to your PHP script.

---

Your PHP script should save all the values either in a database, or in JSON-format in a file on the server. JSON is the easiest. Look into [JSON PHP PARSER](https://www.php.net/json).

---

Last but not least. If you do the right thing, and make sure that every new value that a user enters gets updated in your json file by your PHP script. You can make the last step. which is to make a javascript function that retrieves the JSON file. JSON stand for `JavaScript Object Notation`, so your javascript can use this right away.

What you will do next, is to change all the values in your DOM that look different from the values in your retrieved JSON object.

Comment: Yeah... Could save a lot of time if I find that video. Anyway, could you please elaborate a little more.

Comment: I elaborated. Atfirst i wasnt sure whether you really wanted to know, good thing you commented ;)

Comment: One thing about your example, don't use the `onchange` attribute in the html.  Use jQuery or some other library to bind the `onchange` event of the input element to a function handler instead.  Follow best practices and keep HTML, CSS and JS in separate files.

Comment: Good Point. Prsonally I never used Jquery, i like pure JS

Comment: Great!!! Especially `onchange`! Bdw it was `Node js` that I was searching for!!!! :D I wish I could select your answer, but I have to stick with the question tough. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

two type of protocol, Websocket or WebRTC.

[socket.io](http://socket.io/) is Websocket very popular and easy.

[gevent-socketio](https://github.com/abourget/gevent-socketio) for python

Plenty base on node.js. [sailsjs](http://sailsjs.org/), [deployd](http://deployd.com/), [meteor](https://www.meteor.com/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Bdw how about Tornado? Cause I will be using python/django for the backend. Especially which will be the easiest in terms of learning between those two (Tornado and Node js)?